# Create Fucntion returning Table in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper, stored-functions

`TEMP` table:

| Node | Curr_Cnt | Prev_Cnt | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 20 | 40 | 20 |
| Second | 30 | 70 | 40 |

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NEW_FUNCTION
RETURNS table
IS
    c_rec TEMP%ROWTYPE;
    TYPE c_tab IS TABLE OF c_rec%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    l_c_tab c_tab;

BEGIN
SELECT * INTO c_tab FROM

--**The below with clause starting from with returns the same table structure as above temp table**

( WITH batch_id_dtl AS
  (SELECT a.*,
    rownum rnum
  FROM
    (SELECT MIN(creation_date) min_cr,
      MAX(creation_date) max_cr,
      batch_id
    FROM oalterr.q_audit_results
    GROUP BY batch_id
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
    )a
    WHERE BATCH_ID <= 251940
  ),
  curr_cnt AS
 ......rest of the code......
);

RETURN C_TAB;

END NEW_FUNCTION;
```

The above function returns the following error:

> expression 'C_TAB' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement.

Can anyone please tell me what type should I add in return part and what am I doing wrong in the execution part between `begin` and `end`.

Comment: Please correct the tags below your question, (using [edit]).   `plsql` has to do with Oracle, and noting to do with `mysql` so, the current combination of tags seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Also, please don't tag tools like [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) unless the question is to do with how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

For sample table (the one you posted)

```
SQL> select * from temp;

NODE     CURR_CNT   PREV_CNT       DIFF
------ ---------- ---------- ----------
First          20         40         20
Second         30         70         40
```

create type at SQL level so that function *recognizes* it:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_row as object
  2    (node        varchar2(10),
  3     curr_cnt    number,
  4     prev_cnt    number,
  5     diff        number);
  6  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_tab as table of t_row;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Function returns a *type*; for example, `number`, `varchar2` or - in your case - `t_tab`:

```
SQL> create or replace function new_function
  2    return t_tab
  3  is
  4    l_tab t_tab;
  5  begin
  6    select t_row(node, curr_cnt, prev_cnt, diff)
  7      bulk collect
  8      into l_tab
  9      from temp;
 10    return l_tab;
 11  end new_function;
 12  /

Function created.
```

So far so good. Now, call it. One way is straightforward, just like selecting `sysdate` (which is also a function):

```
SQL> select new_function from dual;

NEW_FUNCTION(NODE, CURR_CNT, PREV_CNT, DIFF)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
T_TAB(T_ROW('First', 20, 40, 20), T_ROW('Second', 30, 70, 40))
```

but that looks kind of ugly. Better way is

```
SQL> select * from table(new_function);

NODE         CURR_CNT   PREV_CNT       DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
First              20         40         20
Second             30         70         40

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create the function with the PIPELINED clause and then, in body, using the native PL/SQL approach, in a loop iterate trough your select as cursor and return each row with PIPE ROW.

Aditionaly, it would be better to declare the return type and the table function in a package and to avoid generic return types.

Ofc. you then use such a function as

select * from table(package.function())

See also: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm